# What new features would you like to see in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Asp.net MVC 3 preview 1 was released at the end of last month. Are there any new features you are excited about or any features you would like to see before it is fully released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Full support for Controllers with Generic Parameters**

```
public GenericController<SomeType> : Controller
```

Generic controllers are quite possibly the greatest MVC timesaver if your doing a lot or business CRUD.  There are so many similarities between the Add methods of almost every MVC  project that it makes sense to abstract these operations out in a Controller that fits all scenarios.

Right now its a little hacky to create a generic controller.  The MVC engine always gets the name wrong (GenericCo vs. Generic) and without full support plugin and libraries that interact with controllers just fall over when they encounter a generic one.

**Make Dropdowns easier to work with**

As a professional MVC tag watcher I've noticed that working with dropdowns is one of the most repeated questions on SO.  The amount of Dropdown questions is a strong indication that something should be done to make it easier or less ... complex?

Answer (score 2):

make checkbox list easy to work with

add T4MVC to the official release

add official helpers for OData

support one javascript library either MS Ajax or jQuery(preferably)

Answer (score 0):

I wish they can add something to **help developer to migrate their previous ASP.NET WebForms application.**